# What are types of Load Balancers involved in the Snowflake Multi-AZ architecture hosted on AWS

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

reading through the page on our community detailing about the multi-az snowflake architecture -

https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/snowflake-delivers-high-availability-by-using-aws-availability-zones

there is a mention on Load balancers.

my question is what type of load balancer is that - network, application or combination of both.

Answer (score 0):

The Snowflake uses load balancer service provided by the hosting Cloud Service. For example, on AWS, Snowflake uses ELB (elastic load balancer):

https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/faq-what-ip-address-range-does-snowflake-use